# Spring MVC image or character generic controller

Tags: spring, http, model-view-controller, handler

I would like to implement a generic controller with one or two methods that react to any GET request.  I am trying to simplify this to the point where I can return byte (image etc.) or character based (XML, CSS) without having to map each content type and put a RequestMapping in for each.

The app must be abel to handle any request with any content type.

My dispatcher is currently set to handle all requests via /.

The couple of attempts I have made so far throw ambigious handler errors, or the mapping doesn;t work to the point where text is sent back as byte[] or the other way around.

Has anyone made anything like this work ?

Regards,
Andy

Comment: You can do whatever you like in a Controller, but from what you're explaining, you might just need a regular servlet, since you're basically describing a Controller that doesn't really use any Spring MVC features. But any code examples for what you're trying to do would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a controller like so

```
@Controller
public class YourController {
    @RequestMapping("/*")
    public String doLogic(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
        OutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();
        out.write(/* some bytes, eg. from an image*/); // write the response yourself

        return null; // this is telling spring that this method handled the response itself
    }
}
```

The controller is mapped to every url and every http method. Spring has a set of [accepted return types](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.1.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#mvc-ann-return-types) for its handler methods. With `String`, if you return `null`, Spring assumes you've handled the response yourself.

As @NilsH commented, you might be better off using a simple servlet for this.